# Securing AD for TFS 2013 access for restricted accounts

Tags: tfs, active-directory

We have a number of external contractors who need to access our TFS server. The external contractors have AD accounts, but we want to restrict those accounts.

We have discovered that (in AD) restricting login to just the TFS server prevents the user being able to access TFS Web Access and services.

How can we restrict the AD account in such a way that they can access TFS, but can't use any other services on the network?

Comment: You probably need to add the FQDN of the TFS server to the list of machines the user is allowed to log on to. Don't use the `find` or `search` option, just enter the name directly and click add.

Comment: So instead id `tfsrv011` or something, enter `tfscrv01.mycompany.domain.com`, whichever name is configured for WebAccess.